# Flutter iOS build failure in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I am using a mac to build the Flutter app using the real device iPhone X (14.7), In android studio application build in iOS but the same application field is in Xcode. I get this build error and can't figure out why it won't go away. I am missing a script of some sort. Does anybody else know why?

```
> /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or
> directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**More Details**

[Mac configuration deatils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boVm2.png)

[Xcode error run into real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ4n4.png)

[Project's 'Build Phases' screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bYBW5e65rxzWAJ4sy18NeWrXMQogVk7O/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ElTomato, probably for reach. wrong attempt tho

Comment: Have you googled the error message? It says theres a missing flutter file. I googled it and found many possible solutions. Have you tried any of these first?

Comment: trying lots of solutions but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

after a lot of builds around, I set these two settings and the build run on to my physical device.

- Open xcode project
- Left side runner
- Top info tab
- Configurations
- Change configurations for debug

The image is below for further reference
[**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLlz.png)